# Loading external sites into Iframe dynamically - is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've build an application which currently uses an Iframe to load external sites.

This method is really slowing my application down - taking up to 5 seconds to load a page that
might load in <1sec in it's own tab/window.

Is there any solution I can implement which will let get more speed?!?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Change iFrame on a Button Click Event
$("#myButton").click(function(event){            
    $("#myIFrame").attr('src', $('#url').val());
});

</script>

<input class="url_top" type="text" id="url" value="http://">
<a id="myButton" href="#">Load</a> 
<iframe id="myIFrame" height="80%" width="100%" class="netframe" src="page.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: You haven't given enough detail.  What is the application? What is it doing with the external sites?

Answer (score 1):

@Simon, if you are loading sites into an iFrame then you are probably doing a thumbnail right?  Doing this is going to be slow as each page needs to render in yours so you are contending with the speed of the external site by a factor of n where n is the number of sites on your page.

Please provide more info on what the outcome is that you want so that the greatter community can advise on perhaps different tactics.

Comment: We're actually using this method for manual review of sites for content to ensure safe browsing for children.  When sites get flagged - a manual reviewer loads a list of sites and keeps clicking a "next button" - checks the page/reads the reason for flagging - and approves/disapproves the flag.  Therefore we need to load the page as fast as possible to process more pages/hour

Answer (score -2):

You should jQuery with the function

```
$(function(){ $("#NameImage").css('display','none')})
```

But you should use the function of jQuery v1.7.3

Comment: Why the recommendation to use an older version of jQuery? The current release is 1.8.1.