# How to load page dynamically in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I just want to load an html page in iframe on clicking a link or button  in the same page. I used javascript to load the page dynamically. But, I couldn't do that. Please anyone guide me to do that. My code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById("iframeelem").src="newhtml.jsp";
```

Comment: try this `window.frames[iframeName].location = url;` and see what happenes, and assign the url as absolute url like `http:www.something.com/newhtml.jsp`

Answer (score -7, accepted):

See here. A great help  :

- [Loading pages in iframe dynamically](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37635.aspx)

Though a bit off topic, a good side reading :

- [Loading external sites into Iframe dynamically - is there a better way??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800542/loading-external-sites-into-iframe-dynamically-is-there-a-better-way)
- [How to dynamic load the document content into an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399417/how-to-dynamic-load-the-document-content-into-an-iframe)

Comment: Sorry, but why is this tagged as the answer? This question is tagged and is relevant to javascript; this link is about .net.

Comment: @ThomasMcCabe - where do you see .NET? The question is obviously on how to change an src of an iframe with javascript.

Comment: @Dementic Yes. the question is about how to change with JS, and the answer links to a .NET solution.

Answer (score 4):

Put this on the embedded page

```
<p>
<input type='button' name='Next' value='Next Page'
onclick='window.location.replace("http://timecrystal.co.uk/");' />
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. 
Here is a tutorial, just in case: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/

**What is the error?**

Verify the id of your frame and url are correct (type in the url in a browser window and make sure you get your page).