# Get url query string and use as src on iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completely new at javascript and I'm wondering about something really elementary here. I've got an iFrame that I want a dynamic src on. This src(source) should just be a variable. And then a script sets that variable before the frame is loaded.

It's actually a webpart in Sharepoint 2010, so I set up the webpart and edit it's HTML source to something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">


var qs = getQueryStrings();
var myParam = qs["myParam"]; 

function getQueryStrings() { 
  var assoc  = {};
  var decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, " ")); };
  var queryString = location.search.substring(1); 
  var keyValues = queryString.split('&'); 

  for(var i in keyValues) { 
    var key = keyValues[i].split('=');
    if (key.length > 1) {
      assoc[decode(key[0])] = decode(key[1]);
    }
  } 

  return assoc; 
} </script>

<iframe height="500" src="(myParam);" width="800"></iframe>
```

I'm not even sure the syntax is correct. Basically, I want to insert the variable into the src of the iframe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142825/how-to-load-page-dynamically-in-iframe  You will need to give your iframe an id and maybe a name too.

Comment: And your src can't be just a query parameter, it must be a url.

Comment: Yeah, the querystring should contain the full url I wanted to open. The goal is to have an iframe that works as a PDF reader. So I've got a list of PDF files on one side. And when I click on each of them, it changes the url of the iframe to display that url instead.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give some class or ID to your Iframe.
And then you can call a function which will give src to i frame dyanmically.
from client side use this:

```
$('#ID_of_Iframe').attr('src','NEW SRC hERE');

Example: $('#ID_of_Iframe').attr('src','www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your links like this:

```
<a href="file1.pdf" onClick="window.frames['myPdfFrameName'].location ='file1.pdf';return false;">File1.PDF</a>
```

or:

```
<iframe name='myPdfFrameName'></iframe>

<a href="" onClick="loadFrame('file1.pdf');">File1.PDF</a>

function loadFrame(href) {
   window.frames['myPdfFrameName'].location = href;
   return false;
}
```

EDIT:  Easiest is probably using target attribute of a link:

```
<a href='file1.pdf' target='myPdfFrameName'>File1.pdf</a>
```