# How to change the iframe content by changing the select option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select box and a iframe. when I change the select option the content in the iframe needs to change. I used jquery to change the iframe src. 
To change the src I have used the following code. It works,If I see in the view source I can see the change of src value.But the content is not changing in the iframe.

```
$('#myframe').attr('src', "http://www.option"+value+".html");
```

**Question: How to make this new src url to load my iframe?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load page dynamically in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142825/how-to-load-page-dynamically-in-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use this tactic (there are various issues with it, IE dislikes blank srcs for example).

Instead, remove and recreate a new iframe with the new src.

```
$('#myframe')
    .before('<iframe src="blah.htm"></iframe>')
    .remove();
```